# Time-out for Threads in Boost using Posix Time

Tags: c++, boost

I have created a number of threads in C++ using the Boost Threads library,
I want to time-out all these threads, I can use the `timed_join()` in a loop, but this can make the total waiting time = number-of-threads * time-out-time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
{
   threads[i]->timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeout_time));
}
```

So, I'm thinking of using the builtin posix_time class to calculate the deadline for each thread. This way the total wait time is at most the given timeout-time.

What would be the simplest and most straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the overload of `thread::timed_join` that takes an absolute time (i.e. time point) instead of a duration. Make that absolute time deadline be the current time plus whatever timeout duration you desire. This will ensure that none of `thread::timed_join` calls in the loop will wait past the absolute time deadline.

In the latest version of Boost.Thread (as of Boost 1.50), Boost.Date_Time is now deprecated in favor of [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/chrono.html). This is to closer match the API of [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) in C++11.

This example shows how to specify an absolute time deadline with either Boost.Chrono or Boost.DateTime:

```
using namespace boost;

#if BOOST_VERSION < 105000

// Use of Boost.DateTime in Boost.Thread is deprecated as of 1.50
posix_time::ptime deadline =
    posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() +
    posix_time::seconds(timeoutSeconds);

#else

chrono::system_clock::time_point deadline =
    chrono::system_clock::now() + chrono::seconds(timeoutSeconds);

#endif

for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
{
    threads[i]->timed_join(deadline);
}
```

This [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/examples/general_usage_examples.html) in the documentation shows Boost.Date_Time example usages.

This [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html#chrono.users_guide.tutorial) in the documentation is a tutorial on Boost.Chrono.

Answer (score 0):

```
int64_t mseconds = 60*1000; // 60 seconds
```

simply use

```
threads[i]->timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(mseconds ))
```

you dont need to use absolute time